# What does ... mean in file path in linux(ubuntu) or git

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

When I ran the command `git pull` all updated files are shown and their paths are relative to `.git` file.
But due to some reason I am seeing `...` in file path. Am I am unable to do to the path as linux has `.` and `..` according to my knowledge which represents current and previous directory resp.
Attaching my output

```
$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 72, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (72/72), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
remote: Total 43 (delta 28), reused 7 (delta 4), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (43/43), done.
From ssh://gitlab-master.xyz.com:12051/projectx/santor
   234243..434323  master                         -> origin/master
   989894..324342  branch-xyz                     -> origin/branch-xyz
Updating 480026d82..e87fa34343
Fast-forward
 .../modules/files/text/jump/jumps.yaml       | 3476 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 .../modules/files/text/drink/jumps.yaml      |  228 +++-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in the file path.

It *does* mean something in the Git output: that Git *isn't printing* part of the path.

When Git produces `git diff --stat` output like this, it needs to print various file names, but it has a limited amount of columnar space in which to print them.  So it uses compression tricks.  One of these is to *leave out* parts of the pathname, representing the left-out part with `...`.  That is what you are seeing here.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have a general specified meaning. This is just a way for Git to display an abbreviated path when the whole thing would break screen formatting.